# Teamcity and Angular 7

Tags: angular, teamcity, angular7

My app was built on Angular 5, and the code used to deploy perfectly fine, we upgraded it Ng7, now, even though the build goes fine, when it gets deployed, it gives the error as 'tinymce is not defined'. However when I do a local prod build and run it in, it works perfectly, fine, if I put the same local dist folder directly on the server, it works fine. But when I deploy it via teamcity, it gives this error and stops the whole app. Do I need to make some changes on teamcity as well when I upgrade it to Ng7?

I apologize in advance, saying this is just text, because I understand the code is working perfectly fine, just that teamcity might be doing something.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if teamcity agents have the same environment configuration as your local machine. 
- npm version
- node version
- cli version